# Disallow access by default unless user has specific role using Spring Security

Tags: spring-security, configuration, annotations

I want to configure spring-security so that it disallows request to my REST endpoints by default, only allowing access when I specify access conditions.

Instead of annotating each controller method using @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()") I can make the following configuration

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests()
    .anyMatchers("/public/**).permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Is there a similar configuration option for roles? I want to make all my endpoints inaccessible by default and having to specify the required roles per endpoint method (or that for that endpoint no role is required).

That way, should I forget to specify the required role or that no role is required, no one will have access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

secure api by roles

eg.

```
 http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/*")
    .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the required roles with an annotation on the method? Then you can specify the required role on the service method. If you use the service method in say a desktop application it has the same role requirement without having to make the configuration again for the desktop client.

Comment: yes you can use  '@Secured` annotation on service methods, eg  @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")
You need to enable it
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)

Comment: And is there a way to prevent access to service methods unless I annotate them with @Secured("ROLE_ADMIN")?